# How to tag an element below form elements so that the screen reader picks it up

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Say I have a div with some p tags below some text elements, how do I aria tag these so the screen reader picks these up?

I could give the div tagindex="0" but my linter complains:

> `tabIndex` should only be declared on interactive elements

Is the linter right or are there aria tags, I can use for this?

```html
<div>
  <label for="text">Text</label>
  <input id="text" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
  <p>How can I get this picked up</p>
  <p>Should I put tabindex=0 on parent div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may do two copies of them. One is hidden from the screens but is visible for the screen readers, but another one is visible for the screens, not for readers.

Comment: If by "pick up" you mean screen reader users to be able to read them, you don't have to do anything, a screen reader picks up paragraphs as text just fine.

If the text below is related to the form, i.e. describes the field's functionality, you can use [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute)

Comment: i mean if they tab off the input field, they will skip by the text unless the tabindex=0 but my linter comes pains about this

Comment: @dagda1: Why should the `p` elements not be skipped when pressing Tab there? Why do you want them to become focused?

Comment: i want the screen reader to read them out.  i’m just curious why the limiting rule exists

Answer (score 1):

Screenreaders have different navigation mode.

While tabbing through elements give the same user experience as your own (i.e. only focusing elements who have a `tabindex`, links, forms, ...), users navigate through the whole document in reading mode (using combination of keys or arrows) which permits to read all the content.

So you have nothing to do. As long as the text is visible, it will be read.